# CN characters doesn't work in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, character-encoding

I have a multilanguage project, where i have CN (chinese) too. The characters works on every browsers, except IE8. I'm using the folowing meta tag for encoding.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Maybe i miss something. If anyone got an idea I would appreciate it.

Comment: “Doesn’t work” is not a problem description. Show a complete, preferably minimal example that demonstrates what happens and *say* what happens (e.g., “the Chinese character  appears as a dancing pink elephant”).

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tag too and this will work.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="zh-CN"/>
```

**zh** is primary-code of Chinese.

Comment: The added tag would, at most, affect the choice of glyphs for CJK characters, in case the page does not set their font. Then it would select specifically Simplified Chinese glyphs. (We cannot know from the question whether this is desired.)

Comment: In place of chinese characters apeears only squares. I tried to use normal Arial font, i think maybe my font doesn't have chinese characters, but no changes were made.

Comment: @user3309622, please edit your *question* to clarify what happens (and include a testable example).

Answer (score 0):

I just realised what happens. Now it works with the normal UTF-8 encoding.
So my problem was that I installed windows XP with native IE8 for testing, but some language pack were missing, so for chinese characters didn't used any font.

If some1 got this issue, you can check like this:

1. Go to /tools/internet options/fonts/
2. Set the "Language Script" to Chinese Simplified
3. Select the only option - Arial Unicode MS
4. Accept the changes- problem solved.

Sorry for my question, it was inattention from my side. Anyway hope I helped some others who got the same problem.